# Could we remove the note "Not the answer you're looking for?" in threads where you post an answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers

There's this text near the bottom of each *thread* (Q&As):

> Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged
>    or ask your own question.

if you post an answer in a *thread*, it's likely that you're not looking for an answer, so my suggestion is removing that *Not the answer you're looking for?* part from *threads* where you have posted an answer as it's quite pointless in such case, I'd say. What do you think?

Comment: Minor, but makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense, but perhaps *too* minor? How often do you linger after posting an answer to see that and be bothered by it? We've usually read the thread, and right after answering just move on. Versus scripts having to check to see if you have answered, and if yes remove text, else leave text. Seems a lot of fiddling for little return. Also, users who *do* answer might click the "Browser other question tagged.." and answer more similar question.